# Finding interface name for destination address using routing table

Tags: c, linux, routes

i'm trying to find a linux C function which should obtain interface name(or id) of ipv6 destination address using routing informating.

I want use this interface name to send my raw packet through pcap_inject()

Does something like this exist? or i have to popen ip -6 route and parse information from this output?

Comment: The post is short but might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750006/how-to-programmatically-edit-the-routing-table/750056#750056 as entry, as it gives a hint how to read the routing table entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is ICMPv6 protocol, messages are NeighborAdvertisment and NeighborSolicitation