# Modifying Linux kernel routing table programmatically

Tags: linux-kernel, routes

While browing through /proc, I am across `/proc/net/fib_trie` which seems to have main routing table of kernel inside it. My question is if modifying it will change the routing table or it is a stat only file?

(I want to modify routing table programmatically and I am total noob in C so looking for other options. File modification will be easy in any language)

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750006/how-to-programmatically-edit-the-routing-table), [MattSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20889/mattsmith) mentioned in a comment that modifying the file `/proc/net/route` and using **ioctls** is a solution, Can someone please guide me how?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is if modifying it will change the routing table or it is
>   a stat only file?

No, route table won't change as file is read-only.

> In another question, MattSmith mentioned in a comment that modifying
>   the file /proc/net/route and using ioctls is a solution, Can someone
>   please guide me how?

From user space perspective you can use netlink sockets to manage routing table.
See some C [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788326). However, it would be difficult for newcomer.

So the easiest way is to use [ip](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) utility(in fact it uses netlink sockets). That way, you can implement your own shell script and execute routing manipulations within it. You can search for proper [usage](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html) of **ip** tool.

Comment: it is *iproute2* package for shell. I know about it. My question is specifically about using programming language.

Comment: In fact, shell is scripting language and it's easy to get start with. So again, less time consuming option is to write shell script. The hard thing would be using netlink.